# how to declare an object globally in Flask

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, global-variables

I'm using the latest Flask version and I followed the official tutorial to create an app.
So I have the `__init__.py` file defined in this way:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, g
from . import requests_page, customer
#application factory function
def create_app(test_config=None):
# create and configure the app
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='dev', #should be changed with a random key when deploying
) 
...
#other init stuff

#IMPORTANT LINES
app.cus = customer.FirstCustomer()
app.cus.set_model_instance_path(app.instance_path)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = app.cus.get_data()
    return data

app.register_blueprint(requests_page.bp)
return app
```

Then I have the `customer.py` file defined in this way:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import os
from sdv.tabular.base import BaseTabularModel
from sdv.tabular import GaussianCopula

class Customer(ABC):
    model_path = ""
    model = BaseTabularModel()

    @abstractmethod
    def set_model_instance_path(self, p):
        ...

    def get_data(self):
        ...
        return data

class FirstCustomer(Customer):
    def set_model_instance_path(self, p):
        ...
```

and finally the `requests_page.py` defined as:

```
from flask import (
Blueprint, flash, g, current_app, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
) 
bp = Blueprint('index', __name__)

@bp.route('/getdata')
def get_data():
    data = current_app.cus.get_data()
    return data
```

As you can see in `__init.py__`, I have assigned my custom "cus" object as if it is a field of the app object. I have done this in order to make sure that the "cus" object is accessible in other Python files as well, for example, `requests_page.py` through the current_app object. And it works, I can access the object. But I was just wondering, is it clean and legit to do so, or is there some other cleaner way?

Answer (score 2):

You can put your `cus` variable in global in `__initi__.py`. And import this variable into `requests_page.py`.

This will prevent you from putting your `cus` object in `app`.